# Palantir foundry using imported dataset to perfomr nlp operation using pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, nlp, palantir-foundry

So I ran this simple code below in Palantir Foundry code workbook and it ran. Now I want to pass it a dataset which I imported and is sitting in my graph. The dataset is a pyspark dataframe which has one column with 1000 rows of text. So I want to substitute `text="some random text"` with a spark dataset that contains many rows.

```
import nltk.tokenize as nt
import nltk
text="Being more Pythonic is good for health."
ss=nt.sent_tokenize(text)
tokenized_sent=[nt.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in ss]
pos_sentences=[nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in tokenized_sent]
pos_sentences
```

Answer (score 1):

In your python transforms, you can wrap your code in an udf. An udf is not very performant but it would allow you to write exactly that code. i.e.:

```
def tokenize(text):
   ss=nt.sent_tokenize(text)
   tokenized_sent=[nt.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in ss]
   return [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in tokenized_sent]

tokenize_udf = F.udf(translate, T.StringType())

df.withColumn("result", tokenize_udf(F.col("text")))
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer...but in pyspark df is not defined...I think I need a line of code somewhere that converts the pyspark data frame to a pandas dataframe.  The error message is: "There is a reference to an undefined function or module called 'df', Please review your code."

Comment: Hey @user601828 you can change the type of dataframe from Pyspark to Pandas in the inputs bar of the code workbook.